# Banner and Interstitial ads not showing?

Tags: android, adsense

I'm New in Android studio i follow all the steps to place banner and interstitial ads.

But ads not showing after signed the apk.
I use Jarsignature and apkfullsignature to sign my apk through AndroidStudio

my question is simple.

1. Do i need to signed apk to show ads ?
2. Do i need to Publish my app to Google Play Console to Show ads ?

What i Try
1. I sign My apk through "Apk Editor Pro" after signed It will Start Showing ads
 but how i don't Know.
2. I use My Friends Keystore(.jsk) file to sign my app , and again my app start showing ads, My Friend already Have a play Console account.

What I need to follow
can anyone give a Keystore file to test.
Please Help me to fix this problem , Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sagar Balyan is right, you don't require a signed apk nor a published app to display your ads. If you need to show test ads, please visit https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads to use a sample ad unit that Google provides. However, to show a real advert, you need to have an account on the Google play console to get your specific unit Id's

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to have a Playstore account just for showing ads. You can be shown ads even in the debug mode also. Though i would advise you to include the test key that google provide for developers but this doesn't mean the real key that is produced for your projects is not going to work in the app if it is not uploaded on playstore.

Comment: I'm already use test key by Google banner and interstitial ad unit id , it's work fine but only my original test id of my admob account not working , and also if i sign apk using "apk editor pro" app or use my friend keystore to sign apk its work great , what's wrong in Google admob in India I don't know about new privacy and policies , many Indian users and developer's face this problem.

Comment: No bro , I'm not find any solution Yet, if you find any solution please don't forget to text me.

Comment: Sometimes it takes some time for the ads to show. So try waiting for few days or maybe for few hours.